# How to keep ngx-owlcarousel-o carousel for Angular in center

Tags: html, css

I'm learning Angular. I wanted to create a simple carousel so that I can show my sponsors on homepage. I came across many study materials that talks about `bootstrap` carousel. But I don't want that. I want to use `ngx-owlcarousel-o`. I followed exactly as mentioned in their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o). And sorry, i thought pasting code here can be very confusing for all. To save everyone's time and effort I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6fqdm). My problem is that I'm not getting slide in the center. They're aligned to left no matter what css i apply. Please correct me.

This is my **card-holder.component.html**

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
  <ng-template carouselSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>  
  <ng-template carouselSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>  
  <ng-template carouselSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>  
  <ng-template carouselSlide>Slide 4</ng-template>  
  <ng-template carouselSlide>Slide 5</ng-template>  
  <ng-template carouselSlide>Slide 6</ng-template>  
</owl-carousel-o>
```

And this is the css file:
**card-holder.component.css**

```
owl-carousel-o {
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

I tried taking help from:

1. [CSS Layout - Horizontal & Vertical Align](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_align.asp)
2. [angular ngx-bootstrap carousel not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166705/angular-ngx-bootstrap-carousel-not-centered)

I also tried wrapping everything inside a `div` and the tried:

1. [How to horizontally center a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

But it is so stubborn. Not ready to move even by 1 pixel. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaen88 .

Your should add "center" property to your owl configuration and text-align:center to .owl-item